# how to hide/show dom element in google closure

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

domA.style.display = "none"; 
    domA.style.display = "block;

I could not find such functions in the library, but I guess they must have it somewhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    goog.require('goog.style');
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="myElement">test</div>
</body>
</html>
<script> 
    goog.style.setStyle(goog.dom.$("myElement"), "display", "none");
    // or
    goog.style.showElement(goog.dom.$("myElement"), false);
</script>
```

Comment: according to what folks say on closure group,  $ functions will probably be removed in favor of goog.dom.getElement('myElement') style functions

Comment: This approach is now outdated, as below :)

Answer (score 5):

Another option is

var elA = goog.dom.getElementByClass('sdf');

goog.style.showElement(elA, true) // show element

goog.style.showElement(elA, false) // hide element

Comment: This is deprecated. Use setElementShown() instead.

Answer (score 4):

According to the more recent [official documentation here](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_style_style.js.html), the following is recommended for `setStyle`:

> Sets a style value on an element. ... When possible, use native APIs:
>   elem.style.propertyKey = 'value' or (if obliterating old styles is
>   fine) elem.style.cssText = 'property1: value1; property2: value2'.

This would suggest `goog.dom.getElement('myElement').style.display = 'block';` as in your question.

It's also helpful to note that if you use `showElement`, setting the second argument to `true` will return the element to its `default style`. As it says:

> True to render the element in its default style, false to disable
>   rendering the element.

What this means, though, is that if you set `display: none` in your CSS, setting `true` still won't show the element because the CSS default style is to hide the element!! This is different than, say, with jQuery.

To toggle, you can do this:

```
var el_style = goog.dom.getElement('myElement').style;
el_style.display = (el_style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none");
```

Comment: The link "official documentation here" seems now broken.